# Wordpress Custom Post category archive

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, wp-list-categories

I have a custom post type set up, with a number of categories and sub categories.

What I am trying to do is create a page that shows all the posts in a specific category, with a menu that lists all the category sub categories so the posts can then be filtered.

I have tried copying the archive template and renaming it taxonomy-(my-custom-taxonomy).php which then if I go to the slug shows certain posts, and using 
    `<?php wp_list_categories(); ?>`  but I just want a list of all the sub-categories of a specific category, and to filter those posts. I am struggling to show these and use one template for all categories and children.

Comment: You use `category-slug.php` instead of taxonomy for category filtering. To only show children, `<ul> 
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=id&show_count=1&use_desc_for_title=0&child_of=8'); ?>
</ul>` Where 8 is the category ID.

Comment: I want to use one template for all pages so this answer would not work. Where has the other answer gone? I thought it was almost there.

Comment: They must have deleted their answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
```

and

```
$tax= get_query_var( 'taxonomy' )
```

to return the details of the current term and taxonomy being viewed in your taxonomy.php page.

You can then use that info with [`get_term_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) to get the child terms of the current term being displayed. For examples, see the link provided

**EDIT**

Your code should look like this

```
<?php
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ); 
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    echo '<ul>';
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';

    $args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy_name,
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $term->slug,
            ),
        ),
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<p>' . get_the_title() . '</p>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    echo '</ul>';   

}
?>
```

Comment: So would I do the following code, because it doesnt seem to show anything: `<?php

$term_id = get_query_var( 'term' );
$taxonomy_name = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
 $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
 echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>`

Comment: You missed a line in my first code. I've updated my answer with a working example

Comment: I am getting an error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on  the term_id line

Comment: Strange that you get that error. Updated my code with a new approach

Comment: Your updated code is now showing a list of the child categories, but not all the posts - how can I get it to show all the posts from the page and sub pages, and then filtering down when I select a child category

Comment: Just do a simple `WP_Quey` inside the foreach loop

Comment: How would I do this to show the results below the bulleted list?

Comment: I've updated my code. That should give you a basic idea. Just add your own html mark up

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have sub categories within the sub categories - how can I show these as an indented list of the parent?

Comment: The sub-child aren't working rather the ul li is being wrapped around every link. The posts aren't coming up below the list but within the list.

Comment: This is the bare bones. I would really think that this would be able to help you achieve your goal.> if any one want to,please use my code to work towards a solution. Unfortunately I don"t have time to code now